# undefined reference when linking dynamic library in Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, linker, dynamic-library

i have written such a code in my Ubuntu system:

my.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int set(void);
```

lib.c

```
#include "my.h"
int set(void) {
  a = 100;
  return 0;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "my.h"

int main(void){
  set();
  printf("a = %d\n", a);
  return 0;
}
```

and then i use follow commands to build them:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmy.so -I. lib.c

gcc -L. -lmy -I. -o test main.c
```

when i build the test, i get the error information :

```
main.c:(.text+0x5):undefined reference to 'set'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

> but when i use the same code run in Fedora23 and Fedora24, it works well.

so i want to know why can this happen? is there any limitation in Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have fallen foul of a difference between the linkage conventions of
Fedora's GCC builds and Debian/Ubuntu's GCC builds.

When you invoke `gcc` to perform linkage of a C executable it in turn invokes the system linker
`ld`, passing it your commandline linkage options and silently adds to
them a large number of "boilerplate" linkage options which are invariant
for C language linkages (similarly for `g++` and C++ language linkages).

Those invariant linkage options are decided by your distro and configured
into their build of GCC. So they are *not* invariant across distros.

Debian/Ubuntu GCC silently adds `--as-needed` to the linkage options at a
position before your input files and libraries. Fedora's GCC does not.

The effect of `--as-needed` is to make the linker link a shared library
that it finds in the linkage sequence *only* if that library provides
a definition of one or more symbols for which the linker has *already* found
undefined references (i.e. within object files or libraries earlier
in the linkage sequence). This behaviour applies in any case for static libraries.
So `--as-needed` makes the linkage rules similar for both static and shared
libraries - which might be considered helpful to the average user.

This difference is a linkage policy difference between the distros. What it
means to you is that to link successfully on Ubuntu, your linkage commandline
must mention any library *after* any object file or other library that depends
on it. And if you are compiling-and-linking in one command, then you must
mention any library *after* any source file whose corresponding object file
depends on that library. So on ubuntu, your problem commandline should be:

```
gcc -I. -o test main.c -L. -lmy
```

to succeed. This will also of course work for Fedora.

If you are interested in inspecting the hidden differences in the linkage
options between the two distros you can reveal them by add `-Wl,-v` to your
compile-and-link command to get verbose linker output.

Comment: thanks your reply. it solves my problem. And i want to know can i change the default LD flags so that for each library the default property is `--no-as-needed` like in FEDORA. Where does the default link arguments come form? thanks!

Comment: @pakade You can't change this behaviour without building your own GCC toolchain. In Ubuntu -
as in Fedora - its better to get used to the rules than fight them. In some countries
you drive on the left of the road, in others you drive on the right. Most
linux devs today don't even know its possible to link shared libraries the
way you're used to. If you really wanted to do it like that on Ubuntu, you'd
use e.g. `gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed -L. -lmy -I. -o test main.c -Wl,--as-needed`.
But anyone would prefer `gcc -I. -o test main.c -L. -lmy`